# Outbound URL rewrite IIS 7 ARR crashing application

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, url, arr

I'm having trouble with setting up a reverse proxy outbound URL redirect in IIS 7 with ARR. The domain has 2 inbound URL rewrites and 1 outbound URL rewrite. The inbound ones work fine and I haven't seen any problems with them.

However the outbound redirect seems to crash the application pool every time it is enabled. And it will keep crashing until I disable the outbound rule. I think it might be some kind of loop in my redirects but I'm not sure. I'm not too familiar with regex myself and I haven't been able to find much from searching online.

Here are the 2 inbound redirects that work:

```
<rule name="Rule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^blog/$" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="0" />
                    <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="domain.com" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.domain.com" appendQueryString="True" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^blog/(.*)" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="0" />
                    <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="domain.com" />
                    <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" value="{REMOTE_ADDR}" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.domain.com/blog/{R:1}" appendQueryString="True" />
            </rule>
```

And here is the outbound rule that causes the app pool to crash when it is enabled:

```
<outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
            <rule name="outRule1" preCondition="isHtml" enabled="false" stopProcessing="false">
                <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^http(s)?://blog.domain.com/blog/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://www.domain.com/blog/{R:2}" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="isHtml">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to set `rewriteBeforeCache` to false for your outbound rules

Paul

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you should include some explanation with your answer.